# How do I exclude algorithms from H2O AutoML in Sparkling Water by using Scala

Tags: scala, sparkling-water

I have to exclude some algorithms from AutoMl model.

I am trying this to exclude algorithms but it fails.

```
buildSpecHopper_1.build_models.exclude_algos = Array(Algo.DeepLearning,Algo.GLM)
```

But it throws Class cast exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lai.h2o.automl.AutoML$algo; cannot be cast to [Lai.h2o.automl.Algo;
```

Answer (score 0):

in Sparkling Water, the proper way how to use AutoML is via our Spark wrapper:
 https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/078f38ae5c863f7203cbdc9c35110f23c557d756/examples/pipelines/hamOrSpamMultiAlgo.script.scala#L97

That wrapper has options to both specify include and exclude algos.

I can see that you are using directly the Java API and probably hit a bug. We will have a look on that, but I advice to use the higher level API.